# Issuer mismatch : WSO2 IS and Spring Boot but same URI configured

Tags: spring-boot, wso2

I'm just reproducing the WSO2 IS official tutorial here : https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/spring-boot/

There for in Spring, my OIDC configuration is simply :

```
provider:
  host: https://localhost:9443 #Change the host
  
spring:
   security:
     oauth2:
       client:
         registration:
           wso2:
             client-name : WSO2 Identity Server
             client-id: aXOWlNxT0aKIfKIeH82IfsmLjsYa #Change client-id
             client-secret: CVl_vmEYqRuZddBu3ZCYQQwGtYsa # Change client-secret
             authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
             scope: openid
         provider:
           wso2:
             issuer-uri: ${provider.host}/oauth2/oidcdiscovery
   thymeleaf:
     cache: false
```

Nonetheless, I still get this Error :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: **The Issuer
> "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token" provided in the configuration
> metadata did not match the requested issuer
> "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/oidcdiscovery"**   at
> org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97)
> ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]    at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.withProviderConfiguration(ClientRegistrations.java:239)
> ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]  at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.lambda$oidc$0(ClientRegistrations.java:158)
> ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]  at

Also, my WSO2 IS is properly configured. Only defaults. As shown in the screenshot below with Identity Provider configuration

[image]

What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been already reported [[1]](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/8622), and as the solution `/token` endpoint has been configured for the discovery request [[2]](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-samples-spring-boot/pull/2/files).

Comment: I googled but not looked in github results.Thank you. Before your answer, I fixed it by changing  Identity Provider Entity ID from token to oidcdiscovery to match my application.yml. Now, I'll use /token in both settings. I believe the tutorial should be updated also https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/spring-boot/. Thank you Anuradha and please vote up my question